# Synchronize 2 GCS buckets schedulled

Tags: synchronization, scheduled-tasks, google-cloud-storage

Didn't find answer for this, so:
I have my production Google Cloud Storage bucket A, and also a bucket B that I keep only for backup of A, and it's actually in another different Google project. I need that:

- I can make this sync operation once and have it run forever periodically, instead of having to run or trigger it again and again. With periodically I mean daily or weekly, I don't need more often than that.
- Contents go directly from A to B, to avoid the extra cost of transfering everything through a third machine (like my laptop or a ComputeEngine box).
- Preferably it would imply copying only new contents and changes, since 90% will be the same from last sync.

My questions:

1. I think that Storage Transfer Service is the best option but I'd like someone who knows better to confirm. Any better option?
2. Is it true that Storage Transfer Service meets my second requirement and gsutil doesn't? It seems so, but then I'm surprised they don't mention it when the docs say "Should you use gsutil or Cloud Storage Transfer Service?" (https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, I think the [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/) is the perfect solution for your use case. You can set up a recurring transfer.
2. You can also transfer data in the cloud with gsutil, but there are several caveats. See the [Copying In The Cloud And Metadata Preservation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#copying-in-the-cloud-and-metadata-preservation) section of the gsutil rsync docs.